# How to know build in exception or user defined exception

Tags: c#

I have console program like this:

```
int a;
try
{
    Console.Write("Input = "); a = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
    if (a<0)
    {
        throw new Exception("Input Can't < 0");
    }
}            
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Something error");
}
Console.ReadKey();
```

If I input alphabet, it show "Something error". If I input numeric -20, it also show "Something error".

I know if I change the code in block catch to `Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);`, it can show my user define exception. But, I don't want use it.

Is some trick to check the exception is build in or user defined?

Comment: This made my day `catch (Exception ex) { Console.WriteLine("Something error");`

Comment: Use `int.TryParse`.

Comment: Well, the first mistake in your code is that you are using `Convert.ToInt32` instead of `int.TryParse`.  **Never trust user input!**. and I really do mean never.

Comment: Don‘t use exceptions for normal contol flow. Just print your message in the `if` branch.

Comment: @TheGeneral the only thing better then that is `catch (Exception ex) { Console.WriteLine("Your mama!");` I've actually seen code like that IRL once, couldn't stop laughing for a good 5 minutes....

Comment: @ZoharPeled or yoda messages, `hmmm... error you have thrown`

Comment: @TheGeneral the complete message should be `hmmm... error you have thrown, fix the problem you must...`

Comment: @ZoharPeled haha yes indeed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should define a custom exception class, and check for that with a dedicated catch block.

Define a new exception class by deriving from the `Exception` class:

```
public class MyException : Exception
{
    public MyException() { }

    public MyException(string message)
        : base(message)
    { }
}
```

Then throw that exception type in your code:

```
void MyMethod()
{
    int a;
    try
    {
        Console.Write("Input = ");
        a = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        if (a < 0)
        {
            throw new MyException("Input Can't < 0");
        }
    }
    catch (MyException myEx)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("MyException was thrown");
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Some other exception was thrown");
    }
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Comment: Using exceptions for program flow is a horrible idea.

Comment: I didn't downvote your answer. I think it answers the question, but it is missing some stuff. Exceptions are for exceptional things - and invalid user input is not exceptional at all. In this case, using exceptions is the wrong thing to do in the first place, however this is a good answer for the title of the question (just not for the question's content).

Comment: @UweKeim, which is irrelevant to the question.